# VB.Net How Do I raise COM Events

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, com-interop, autoit

I'm trying to integrate Autoit and VB.NET via COM. I've got how to make functions an properties visible to COM but how do i make Events visible to COM

```
<ComClass(Core.ClassId, Core.InterfaceId, Core.EventsId)>
Public Class Core
    Public Const ClassId As String = "790D4506-D57D-4E2D-935A-1CC02C4B7CB4"
    Public Const InterfaceId As String = "0568FCF5-248C-4853-AFC6-309A838EA978"
    Public Const EventsId As String = "E81585D3-D5C3-4344-A830-D18A54F6A64E"
    Public Event AnEvent As EventHandler
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub newevent(yourstring As String)
        Dim e As DefaultEventArgs = New DefaultEventArgs(yourstring)
        RaiseEvent AnEvent(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DefaultEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs
    Dim str As String
    Public Sub New(astr As String)
        Me.str = astr
    End Sub
End Class
```

And The Autoit Code

```
Func MyHandler($test)
    MsgBox(0,"","It's Finally Working")
EndFunc
DllOpen("Au3Magic.dll")
$test = ObjCreate("Au3Magic.Core")
if IsObj($test) then
    MsgBox(0,'',"No COM Failure")
    ObjEvent("Au3Magic.AnEvent","MyHandler")
    $test.newevent("test")
Else
    MsgBox(0,'',"Complete COM Failure")
EndIf
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your class out so that you use separate interfaces for the Events and methods, then create a delegate and get your event to call that.

Here is a skeleton for a COM Interop class that raises an event called `UpdateProgress`

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"), _
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
Public Interface IEventSkeletonEvents
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(1)> Sub UpdateProgress(ByVal progressPercentage As Int32)
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"), _
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)> _
Public Interface IEventSkeleton
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(1)> Function Suspend() As Boolean
End Interface

<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")> _
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(IEventSkeleton))> _
<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(IEventSkeletonEvents))> _
Public Class EventSkeleton : Implements IEventSkeleton

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(False)> _
    Public Delegate Sub UpdateProgressDelegate(ByVal progressPercentage As Int32)
    Public Event UpdateProgress As UpdateProgressDelegate

    Public Function Suspend() As Boolean Implements IEventSkeleton.Suspend
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            RaiseEvent UpdateProgress(i * 10)
        Next
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: So what would be the event <dllname>.EventSkeleton